# Как вывести вместо только отдельный блок из википедии по запросу

Tags: python, бот, wikipedia

Как вывести вместо полной строки (content) только определенную секцию. К примеру на Python чтобы выводило только само описание?

```
import amino
import requests
import os
import wikipedia
    if content.lower().startswith("wiki"):
        sub_client.send_message(message=str(wikipedia.page("Python").content), chatId=data.message.chatId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что именно вам нужно. Можете попробовать взять `wikipedia.page("Python").summary` - краткое описание.

По уточнённой формулировке вопроса из комментария. Насколько я понял, абзацы отделены просто переводами строки, можно взять текст из `content` до первого перевода строки:

```
wikipedia.page("Python").content.split('\n')[0]
```

Comment: Если выводить контент - выводится фулл страница, а это огромный объем данных. Мне нужно чтобы при запросе питон выводилась первый фулл абзац до разрыва
Python (МФА: [ˈpʌɪθ(ə)n]; в русском языке встречаются названия пито́н[16] или па́йтон[17]) — высокоуровневый язык программирования общего назначения с динамической строгой типизацией и автоматическим управлением памятью[18][19] и продолжалось до конца первого абзаца. такое возмодно?